# JPA: Why save and saveAll are working async?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using JPA save and saveAll to save entities on my application.
But I've 2 different behaviour:

*first case*:
in a method that return the list of saved entities

```
List<Entity> savedEntities = entityRepo.saveAll(listEntitiesToSave);
voidMethod(savedEntities);
return savedEntities;
```

In this first case entities are stored immediately. This is the behaviour that I expected.

*second case*:
in a void method, as last line

```
entityRepo.saveAll(listEntitiesToSave);
```

In this second case entities are not stored immediately: I think that could be possible only because in the first case the saved entities are used. 
How is it possible? Do I need add flush()? But also in this case it's strange.
I don't have async active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my mistake: the parent method that call my saving methods had `@Transactional` on top. 
Transactional call `flush` method only when the method is finished. This was my case:

```
@Transactional
private void parentMethod(){

  service.mySavingMethod1();
  service.mySavingMethod2();
  anotherService.sendEmail();
}
```

So the user received the email before `mySavingMethods` had finished.
I tried 2 solutions:

- Fast way: adding, where needed, flush after save/saveAll
- Elegant way: remove @Transactional on parent method, create another service, put the list of savingMethods and add the annotation @Transactional. So we'll have:

  ```
  private void parentMethod(){
   newMiddleService.mySavingMethods();
   anotherService.sendEmail();}
  ```

  `@Service
  public class NewMiddleService(){
   @Transactional
   public void mySavingMethods(){
    service.mySavingMethod1();
    service.mySavingMethod2();
   }
  }`

If you need transactional also in the parent method, could be better call on NewMiddleService, `Transactional(propagation = Requires.NEW)`